# Winform Tooltip memory leak. Self disposing Control from timer_tick

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks

Is it possible that when calling multiple times this function:

```
void Func(String spr, PictureBox pictureBox)
{
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
    toolTip.Show(spr, pictureBox, 1000);
}
```

memory leak will occur?

After function is finished tooltip is still there is it even possible that it is just going out of scope and disposing itself?

If the answer is "yes" for the first question, is creating my own toolTip which is self disposing from timer_tick a good solution?

```
public partial class MyToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public MyToolTip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = this.AutomaticDelay;
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If in this case this is not necessary is it applicable in other cases when time of object life is known or is it just bad design?

I've chosen this solution because i want to be able to show many tooltips at the same time.

Comment: I have to ask. Why would you want to show multiple tooltips at the same time?

Comment: @comecme To provide user with information about data input correctness simultaneously showing if resulting values are within certain ranges. I know that is not their typical usage but it was just temporary solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ToolTip` object will still exist in memory after the method has executed and each time the method is called a new `ToolTip` instance is created. It's better to reuse an existing `ToolTip`. e.g.

```
 ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
 void Func(String spr, PictureBox pictureBox)
 {

     toolTip.Show(spr, pictureBox, 1000);
 }
```

**edit**  For multiple tooltips and to dispose explicitly (outside the GC) without the need for a custom object, you could try something (somewhat hacky ;) ) like:

```
 var toolTip= new ToolTip();
 toolTip.Show(spr, pictureBox);
 new System.Threading.Timer(o => tt.Dispose(), null, 1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

The above will work, although, perhaps it would be better to reuse a timer.

Comment: I want to be able to use multiple tooltips at the same time. In this case when tooltip is updated "previous one" will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector will eventually clear the memory used by ToolTip when necessary, so there is no reason to concern yourself with disposing it.

Still, it is much better to use a single ToolTip object instead of creating new tooltips each time you want to show a tip.

Comment: I wonder _when_ the GC will clear the memory. When using a single `ToolTip`, you'll save a reference inside the form. But using the OP's technique, where will a reference to the tooltip be kept? And when will that reference be cleared?

Comment: The memory won't be a problem, the GDI Handle will. If you create a lot of tooltips and they aren't diposed, the handle count will rise quickly. Don't forget windows caps the handle count per process on 10k. If the GC isn't pressurized into collecting due to having enough memory to work with, you can easily hit the handle cap.

Comment: @drake7707 The question was about memory leaks. The handle will be disposed when the Garbage collector collects the unused object. Unless you create several hundred tooltips per hour, this shouldn't be an issue, although it's still ugly coding.